# Deleting worksheet error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete all the sheets except sheet 1. I do not know the name of the worksheets except sheet 1. Hence, I used a for loop but it has always been giving an error of Out of Range Subscript on the line **Worksheets(s).Delete** Thank you for your help in advance.

```
Sub clear()
Dim z, y As Integer
Dim s As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
z = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For y = 2 To z Step 1
s = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(y).Name
Worksheets(s).Delete
Next y
Sheet1.Cells.clear
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI: `Dim z, y as Integer` only sets `y` as an `Integer`. `z` is the default (`Variant`). It's a little un-intuitive to me, but you need to do `Dim z as Integer, y as Integer` if you want to set both as an `Integer`.  Also, do you want to keep `Sheets(1)` or `Sheets("Sheet1")`? They're not *necessarily* the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this but try stepping through the sheets in reverse order. You are probably deleting one of the sheets then trying to reference it in the for loop

```
Sub clear()

    Dim z, y As Integer
    z = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    For y = z To 2 Step -1
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(y).Delete
    Next y
    Sheet1.Cells.clear
End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend you change `Worksheets(s).Delete` to `Sheets(s).Delete` (to be consistent with the counter and the `Name`), but you can combine `s = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(y).Name` // `Worksheets(s).Delete` as `Sheets(y).Delete` anyway.

Comment: Why bother with `s` at all, why not just simply `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(y).Delete`? `z` is also superfluous, an unused variable that does nothing in this context, you can safely omit it.

Comment: @YowE3K Fair enough. I copied the original post and only updated the order of the For Loop. I will edit my answer with you suggestions.

Comment: @DavidZemens - I hope you just mean `z` could be replaced in `For y = z To 2 Step -1` by using `For y = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count To 2 Step -1`.  At the moment `z` is still needed.

Comment: @YowE3K yes, I missed that! But now I see `sheet` is also declared but not initialized or used  :)

Comment: @DavidZemens - Yes, and that one is more of a concern - I hate variable names which look too much like object names.

Comment: I deleted the sheet and s variable. I was trying to show them how to get their code to delete the sheets as close as possible to the way they had it. But all of your suggestions are good suggestions so I incorporated them into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little unclear which sheet you truly want to keep, but how's this?  I'm assuming you want to keep, then clear, `Sheets("Sheet1")`. If not, just edit it to the sheet you do want to keep/clear.

```
Sub clear()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sheet.Name <> "Sheet1" Then sheet.Delete
Next sheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.clear
End Sub
```

If you want to keep `Sheet(1)` then you would do:

```
Sub clear()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sheet.Index <> 1 Then sheet.Delete
Next sheet
Sheets(1).Cells.clear
End Sub
```